# Is there a Facebook API to pull stats from tracking pixels?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm looking through Facebook's API documentation and I'm hunting for any way to pull stats from the tracking pixels to another piece of software, possibly for spreadsheet purposes. Does this exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is the `/v2.6/{ads-pixel-id}/stats` endpoint. From there, you can get (aggregated) event data. You can find the full details here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/ads-pixel/stats/